New project in next.js with ant design having page routing
I want to create a new project in next js with page routing and ant design for the UI. Can somebody give me the steps for it.
I am facing issue in using antd in nextjs project
I have tried-
yarn create next-app app-name
yarn add antd
yarn add @ant-design/cssinjs
then I created-folder-
pages
components
but when ever I reload the project, it gives me error that I cant import out of module and shows this error "cannot use import statement outside a module in node_modules"

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I don't know the exact steps to add antd in next js project
